# Show all items from a database even without a picture

Tags: php, database, select, where-clause

I'm making a webpage that displays my database. I'm using 2 tables for this.

Table 'artikel' and 'images'

Both tables got a key that link to each other: A_ARTCODE and I_ARTCODE

Both keys are the same.

Now I got the problem my keys were not linked and I saw this was, because I didn't used this:

```
WHERE artikel.A_ARTCODE = images.I_ARTCODE
```

So first my page looked like this: [click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mwcadcjbi4ol8cr/wrongid.jpg)

and when I used that code I got this: [click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h9s9krpq0xf0o7c/almost.jpg)

Like you see, now my both ID's are correct.

But I was talking about my tables, in the table 'images' I only got 2 images. Those you see now, but I got like 383 items in my 'artikel' table.

My question now is, how can I display them all? Even the items without a picture?

This is my total php code:

```
    <?php
include('connect-mysql.php');
if (!empty($_GET["page"])) {
    $page  = $_GET["page"];
} else {
    $page=1;
}; 
$start_from = ($page-1) * 20; 
$sqlget = "SELECT *
FROM artikel, images
WHERE artikel.A_ARTCODE = images.I_ARTCODE
LIMIT $start_from, 20
";


$sqldata = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sqlget) or die('error getting');
define('IMAGE_PATH', 'images/');

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(A_ARTCODE) FROM artikel";
$rs_result = mysqli_query($dbcon, $sql) or die ("mysqli query dies");
$row = mysqli_fetch_row($rs_result) or die ("mysqli fetch row dies");
$total_records = $row[0];

$total_pages = ceil($total_records / 20);

echo "<div class='boven'>";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
};

echo "</div>";

echo "<table>";
echo "<tr><th>A_ARTCODE</th><th>A_NUMMER</th><th>A_OMSCHRN</th><th>A_REFLEV</th><th>A_WINKEL</th><th>I_ARTCODE</th><th>I_FILE</th></tr>";

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sqldata)){
    echo "<tr><td align='right'>";
    echo $row['A_ARTCODE'];
    echo "</td><td align='left'>";
    echo $row['A_NUMMER'];
    echo "</td><td align='left'>";
    echo $row['A_OMSCHRN'];
    echo "</td><td align='left'>";
    echo $row['A_REFLEV'];
    echo "</td><td align='right'>";
    echo $row['A_WINKEL'];
    echo "</td><td align='right'>";
    echo $row['I_ARTCODE'];
    echo "</td><td align='right'>";
    echo "<img src='". IMAGE_PATH . $row['I_PATH']. '/' . $row['I_ID']. '.png' ."' />";
    echo "</td></tr>";
    }


echo "</table>";

echo "<div class='onder'>";

for ($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++) { 
            echo "<a href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a> "; 
};

echo "</div>";
?>
```

Comment: U should use a `LEFT JOIN`-sql for this

Comment: Yes indeed, thank you very much. Your sollution works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this U could use a LEFT JOIN sql.
This will give u all records for the articles, even when no images are defined for it

```
SELECT *
FROM artikel a
LEFT JOIN images i
ON a.A_ARTCODE = i.I_ARTCODE
LIMIT $start_from, 20
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use a left join.

```
select *
from artikel
left join images
on artikel.A_ARTCODE = images.I_ARTCODE
LIMIT $start_from, 20;
```

Break yourself of the habit of writing things like `from artikel, images`; this isn't 1989. Use ANSI joins.

Another way is to guarantee that every row has an image. Use a default image (and a default value with a "not null" constraint for it in the table). It might be just a gradient with the text "Picture coming soon" on it.